# Can I access both the original and updated form data from a Symfony constraint validator?

Tags: validation, symfony4, doctrine-odm

I have a Symfony [constraint validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) that is configured to validate a Doctrine ODM document when a form is submitted:

```php
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UserRoleConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

```php
class UserRoleConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $this->dm = $dm;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        // Validation logic here
    }
}
```

Inside the `validate` method I'm able to access the updated form data that is passed in as the `$value` parameter. I also want to access the original document object that was used to pre-populate the form.

I've tried to achieve this by using a couple of techniques, but both seem to return the updated data that was submitted with the form:

```php
// Neither of these get the original document data
$original = $this->dm->find(ClassUtils::getClass($value), $value->getId());
$original = $this->dm->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalDocumentData($value)`;
```

If I use a form event instead of a constraint validator I can get the original data from the event object. However, it makes more sense for this logic to be in a validator rather than a form event.

```php
$original = $event->getData();
```

How can I access the original data from the constraint validator?

Comment: Don't use your document in a form. Use a DTO to pass data to forms, that way your document will stay unmodified unless you do so explicitly allowing you to easily access both new and original data from the DTO and document respectively.

Comment: I think the actual cause of my problem was that my document was referencing other objects that were being changed by the form. The reference was the same in the original and updated documents, so those other objects were updated in the original document as well. Using a DTO helped solve the issue by allowing me to clone the referenced objects in the document that is sent to the form.